# Extract the section of string from a file and store as list with file name

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have several files which look like this.

RF02883_full.txt

```
# STOCKHOLM 1.0

#=GF ID   BcKCsr2
#=GF DE   Burkholderia sRNA 2

AM747720.1/2136330-2136461 AUGAAUGCCAGUUCGCCCCAUAUUUCUCGUAGCUGCGC------CGGUGC--------CCGUUG---------------CAAUGCUUCCC----------GGCACCUGACGC---GCAUCACGACG--GCAU-CAGCCGAGCCGCAUGUCCCUGUCGACGGGGCAGCGGCUUUUUUU
BX571965.1/1703315-1703186 AUGAAUGCCUGUCCGACCCAUUUUUCUCGUAGCUGCGC------CGGUGG--------UCCAAA---------------CGAUGCGCCCA----------CGCGCCUGACGCGCAGCACG---ACG--GUUA-AAGCCGAGCCGCUCGCCCCUGUU--CGGGGGAGCGGCUUUUUUU
```

NF0023_full.txt

```
# STOCKHOLM 1.0

#=GF ID   B
#=GF DE   B 2

BX57195.1/1703315-1703186 AUGAAUGCCUGUCCGACCCAUUUUUCUCGUAGCUGCGC------CGGUGG--------UCCAAA---------------CGAUGCGCCCA----------CGCGCCUGACGCGCAGCACG---ACG--GUUA-AAGCCGAGCCGCUCGCCCCUGUU--CGGGGGAGCGGCUUUUUUU
```

I want to extract the first Identifier and store it in a new file against the file name :
So example output

```
RF02883 AM747720.1/2136330-2136461
NF0023  BX57195.1/1703315-1703186
```

Code I have tried till now :

```
 awk '                             
    /!#=/{                             
      close(file)                     
      file=count=""                  
    }
    (/!#=/ || !NF) && !file{  

}input.txt
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You mentioned that you tried some code, but the code you mention cannot have been tried as it does not even compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. Using `nextfile` which is there in GNU `awk` latest versions and will skip file reading once it finds a line with match which will further save our time too.

```
awk '!/^#/ && NF{print FILENAME,$1;nextfile}' *.txt > Output_file
```

In case you don't have `nextfile` in your awk try following.

```
awk 'FNR==1{found=""} !/^#/ && NF && !found{print FILENAME,$1;found=1}' *.txt
```